# Can Windows Store Apps utilize a second monitor?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Looking to migrate my application to Windows 8 as a side-loaded LOB app but I inherently require 2 monitors. One for full-screen 1080p video and one for touch-input.  Is this possible?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to update the answer to this question.

As of Windows 8.1 RTM you can now run metro apps on multiple monitors simultaneously.

Comment: Correct. There are two ways of doing this that are found in Windows.UI.ViewManagement. One is the ApplicationViewSwitcher class, which allows you to create secondary views that the user can arrange and resize like any other app views. The second is ProjectionManager, which is made for projecting a single view to a second monitor (ala' PowerPoint presentations). See the Multiple Views Sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multiple-Views-Sample-2582fcf3) and the Projection Sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Store apps do not support running on more than one monitor, no.

When you launch a Windows Store app, it will appear on whichever monitor shows the Start Screen when the Windows key is pressed. The end user can change this, if desired, using the Win+PgUp or Win+PgDn shortcut keys.

Comment: After reading into WE8 a bit, I have to wonder if I could utilize WinAPI to accomplish this, since my application would not require certification.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to hack your way around the display model of Windows Store apps, regardless of whether they need to go through store certification. Doing so may put you in an unsupported situation, and result in unpredictable behavior. Better to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Is there a *right tool* for this scenario? There are incredible improvements in touch, graphics capabilities, performance, and UI controls in WinRT. I'm just looking to leverage these benefits I've discovered while making Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Well, if this is a side-loaded app, you could make the video portion a regular desktop app, and the touch input side a Windows Store app, and communicate via local services. Note that this isn't a recommended configuration, since it isn't supported for apps downloaded from the store, but it would likely be better than trying to hack the UI.

Comment: Follow-up...to clarify, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx, using loopback (i.e. local services) is not permitted for apps that are not deployed using Visual Studio. So probably not a workable solution...sorry for any confusion.